# How to add overlapping and horizontally positioned image in fllutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to Position an Image horizontally in a way that it would cover/overlap on the left side of a container , but can't seem to figure out the right way to do it

**Here is what I am trying to achieve:**

[image]

Image is covering the Left edge of the Container.

**This is what I got:**

[image]

There is a gap between the image and container

**Here is my code :**

```
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [ 
                Image(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/btc.png"),
                  height: 47,
                  width: 43,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),  
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.045,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xff2e325c),
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
              ),
              child: Text(
                "1 Token",
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: Color(0xffffffff),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

**UPDATE:**

This is what it looks like when I add it into the stack
Positioning is a little bit off how can I align it with the container like above image

[image]

Comment: use `stack` instead of `row`.

Comment: @Hamed Thanks, I tried using stack , but cant get the positioning right, I have updated the OP to show how it looks like , what would be the best way to Position the Image correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Row(
            children: [
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 8, 0, 0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.055,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xff2e325c),
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "1 Token",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Color(0xffffffff),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.monetization_on,
                    size: 60,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use stack to overlap coin with container.

```
Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.045,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xff2e325c),
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
        ),
        child: Text(
          "1 Token",
          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
            fontSize: 16,
            color: Color(0xffffffff),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Image(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/btc.png"),
        height: 47,
        width: 43,
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: I tried that but positioning is a little bit off , I have Updated the OP with the image to show what it looks like currently

Comment: note: you have to add padding or margin.  
without that, your image will be overlay the text.  moreover, you set the text alingn start.

Answer (score 0):

```
SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.070,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    margin:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.045,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color:  Color(0xff2e325c),
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                    ),
                    child:  Text(
                      "1 Token",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Color(0xffffffff),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/btc.png"),
                    height: 55,
                    width: 55,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```